# count plot for each categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as below, where Q1,Q2,Q3 are categorical.

```
  Q1,Q2,Q3
0    4,1,5
1    1,5,1
2    1,2,1
3    1,4,1
4    5,1,5
```

How can I plot the x axis for each column, and y as the count of the value for each column, all in one plot.

Sample out put

[image]

Comment: If the seaborn part in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68607535/16343464) suits your needs, please add the `seaborn` tag to your question.

Comment: @joseph gan: I added another solution, let me know if you like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on the columns and then plot:

```
# grouped by quartile
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).T.plot.bar()
```

[image: grouped by quartile]

```
# grouped by value
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).plot.bar()
```

[image: grouped by value]

##### old answer

A quick way using pandas only is:

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).plot.bar()
```

But this won't be flexible for the colors/layout.

If you want a nice output, rework your dataframe as long format and use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
df2 = (df.unstack()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'level_0': 'quartile',
                          'level_1': 'index',
                          0: 'value'})
      )
sns.catplot(data=df2, col='quartile', x='index', y='value', kind='bar')
```

output:
[image: seaborn catplot]

I used the following input:

```
   Q1  Q2  Q3
0   4   1   5
1   1   5   1
2   1   2   1
3   1   4   1
4   5   1   5
```

##### combining both answers:

```
import seaborn as sns
df2 = (df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
         .unstack()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'level_0': 'quartile',
                          'level_1': 'index',
                          0: 'counts'})
      )
sns.catplot(data=df2, col='quartile', x='index', y='counts', kind='bar')
```

[image: combined value_counts and seaborn]

Comment: Thanks! I will try both!  first solution,do you mind explaning what does the `(level=0 and axis=1)` in `groupby` do?

Comment: It will group by columns (first level on the columns axis)

Comment: Hi Sorry, just realise my output is not what I intended. What i want was, for example,
for Q1, `1` occur 3 times, `4` occur 1 times and `5` occur 1 times, so the Y-axis shall be the `value_count` and index is the 1,4,5 for Q1. There will be no index 2 & 3 for Q1. Same goes for Q2 and Q3

Comment: You can actually combine this with my previous answer (see edit) to have a graph like in your question (3 panels)

Comment: Thanks! the combine one look alot neater. Will try that out, abit difficult to grasp the `unstack`, `level_0'`, `level_1`. need time to digest. haha

Comment: Well, comment all lines starting with `.xxx` in the pipe and uncomment them one by one from the top to see the intermediates. This will help you understanding what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Import the following modules.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
```

The data as we have it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1':[4,1,1,1,5], 'Q2':[1,5,2,4,1], 'Q3':[5,1,1,1,5]})
```

Put the data into long format:

```
dfn = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['index'], var_name='cat', value_name='number')
```

Display the data as a function of index and category:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="index", y="number", hue="cat", data=dfn)
```

[image]

Display the data as a function of category and index:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="cat", y="number", hue="index", data=dfn)
```

[image]